# How to get the absolute path of a script using its PPID - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, ps

I am trying the absolute path of a given PPID from a shell script.
However, the Parent Process may be any type of script (bash/csh/zsh/tsh/Makefile).

The child process is always a bash script and is the only script I have access on to edit.

**I have tried:**

1. `ps --no-headers -o command $PPID` but it only gets the command that invoked the parent process. This isn't what I need because the parent may have caused some cd's inside the script and I won't be able to resolve the relative path in the command to it.
2. `ls -l /proc/$PPID/fd/255` and this was the closest to what I want but this is specific to bash scripts and as I mentioned, I don't have access to know my parent process' script type.
3. `/proc/$PPID/exe` returns the binary exe, and I need the script's absolute path that is using this binary.

Comment: There's no way to find this information in a way that works for all interpreted languages.  For some languages it may be totally impossible.  For example I'm not sure what you mean by the "absolute path" of a Makefile.  Do you mean that for a given running instance of make you want to find the name of the makefile it's running, from some other process.  That's totally impossible.  I wasn't aware of the bash trick, but I wouldn't rely on it being always the case, and ditto for the others.

Comment: Your best bet is probably `/proc/$PPID/cmdline`, but note that programs have the option to set this to whatever they want.

Comment: Try this `ps -eo pid,cmd | grep $pid`

Comment: @Ivan, `ps` on sufficiently-modern Linux works by reading procfs, so it's a less-direct tool than procfs itself is.

Answer (score 0):

- There isn't such thing as "the" absolute path. There may be several way to access the same file. And some times, none of them (or more than one of them, depends how you look at it) are "the" main name.
  I am thinking of hard links here, for example.
- Makefile is never the path of a script. It is just a configuration file. That is read by default by the executable. Which is probably `/usr/bin/make`. To find a path to the `Makefile` file, you need to read arguments of make. Or to find a `Makefile` among open files (assuming there is only one, and that it is named `Makefile`, and that is not certain). And the strategy to guess what is the `Makefile` of a `make` process is specific to `make`. You need another strategy to guess what is the script file executed by a `bash` process, Another to find what is the python file executed by a python command (which could be a shebang python "executable", a `python ../somerealtive/path/somefile.py` a `python /some/absolute/paht` a `python -m somemodele`, a `python -c "import somemod ; somemod.run()"`  etc.)
- Now, since you've mentioned `/proc/$PPID/exe`, you can get the file "pointed" by this, using
  `path=$(readlink -f /proc/$PPID/exe)`

Again, that is linux solution, more than a bash one. You have no guarantee from bash that the system on which you run this command have a `/proc` filesystem

I must add that I suspect a XY problem here. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have different types of scripts (blackbox) all at the end invoke a set of shell scripts which are editable for me. What I am aiming, is when any of the leaf shell scripts get invoked, I could get the full path of the Invoker Script that called it (Parent script)..all handled through these leaf `sh` scripts. @chrslg

Comment: @MariamFayed, _some_ shells have a well-known file descriptor on which they open the source they're running, but it's not something that's reliable across shells or systems.